# how i could wrapped two command in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Im trying to wrapped this two command in ruby but not work

```
ruby -a -ne 'print $F[0].gsub(/=(.*?)&/," \"\\1\"  and ")' prueban > prueban2

ruby -a   -F';'  -ne    'puts $F[0].sub("less"," <")' prueban2  > prueban3
```

this is my command

```
File.open("text.txt", "r") do  |fi|
  fi.readlines.each do |line|
    parts = line.chomp.split(';')

     fx= puts parts[0].gsub(/=(.*?)&/," \"\\1\"  and ")



    end
   fx.readlines.each do |line|
    parts = line.chomp.split(';')

     fx= puts parts[0].gsub("less"," <")
end
end
```

this is my file

```
pricegreater=2&priceless=4&seleccionequal=pet&
```

and this is my expected output

```
pricegreater "2"  and price < "4"  and seleccionequal "pet"  and
```

I dont know whats is doing wrong please help me

Comment: You really need to get out of the habit of using these one-liners and instead expand that to a full script. It's slightly more lines of code, but it's *incredibly* more readable and maintainable. Using `ruby` to run a Ruby script is just plain incoherent. Make it **one script**.

Comment: yes Im triying to correct but appears error in my script

Comment: my question is about of using a script no one liner

Comment: One script is easier to debug than three that are tangled together like this.

Comment: This question is lacking a lot of context, like a sample file to process, and what the expected outcome is. I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're trying to do here.

Comment: yes i put my file now

Comment: Shouldn't all of `greater`, `less` and `equal` get remapped accordingly?

Comment: I solved now thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a reworked version of the core function to show how to do it in a more Ruby-esque way:

```
# Define a lookup table of all substitutions
REWRITE = {
  'greater' => '>',
  'less' => '<',
  'equal' => '='
}

# Use the lookup table to create a regular expression that matches them all
REWRITE_RX = Regexp.new(Regexp.union(REWRITE.keys).to_s + '\z')

def rewrite(input)
  # Split up each main part of the input on &
  input.split('&').map do |pair|
    # Carve up each part into a var and value on =
    var, value = pair.split('=')

    # Replace terms found in the lookup table
    var.sub!(REWRITE_RX) do |m|
      ' ' + REWRITE[m]
    end

    # Combine these to get the result
    [ var, value ].join(' ')
  end.join(' and ')
end
```

Put into action you get this:

```
rewrite("pricegreater=2&priceless=4&seleccionequal=pet&")
# => "price > 2 and price < 4 and seleccion = pet"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this

```
File.open("text.txt", "r") do  |fi|
  fi.readlines.each do |line|
    parts = line.chomp.split(';')



f = File.open('text2.txt', 'w')

old_out = $stdout
$stdout = f

puts parts[0].gsub(/=(.*?)&/," \"\\1\"  and ")
f.close
  $stdout = old_out


  end
end


File.open("text2.txt", "r") do  |fi|
  fi.readlines.each do |line|
    parts = line.chomp.split(';')



f = File.open('text3.txt', 'w')

old_out = $stdout
$stdout = f

puts parts[0].sub("less"," <")
f.close
  $stdout = old_out

  end
end
```

Comment: You don't need to reassign `$stdout`. You can do `f.puts` to direct output to `f`. Also worth considering: Use `split('&')` to break up the thing into pairs, then `split('=')` to split each pair. This is a lot less mess than hammering it over and over with a regular expression.

Comment: Ok i will take it into account to improve my command ;
thank you very much for your help